# What are the exact charges Fort Worth has dropped in relation to the recent unrest in the US?

Tags: criminal-law, texas

Fort Worth has [dropped all charges](https://www.npr.org/sections/live-updates-protests-for-racial-justice/2020/06/09/872827789/fort-worth-police-drop-rioting-charges-against-protesters-topic-of-a-broad-debat) against people arrested for "rioting" related to the George Floyd protests.  This seems insane to me, which makes me think there is more to this story.  What exactly are these people charged with?  Does it include looting, burglary, throwing things at police, and other things like that, or is it just people who were out past curfew?

Answer (score 1):

### Probably [riot](https://codes.findlaw.com/tx/penal-code/penal-sect-42-02.html), at least that’s what the press release says

Although there may be other charges relating to particular acts within the overall event.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitively for rioting, and not a general amnesty. The letter from Chief Kraus states [in his letter](https://www.nbcdfw.com/news/local/fort-worth-drops-charges-against-50-people-arrested-for-rioting/2385019/) "I am dropping all charged for rioting that have resulted from the protests in Forth Worth".

Comment: I thought charges are by a DA not a police chief. How does this really work?

Comment: I presume this pertains to his prerogative to not further pursue the matter with the DA, and that they were not actually indicted. The media vary in how they describe the situation, and I assume the chief was speaking colloquially in his letter, not technically.